# Span out of main div

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to set css or javascript to detect that span came out of a div?

```
<div class="divMain"> 
 <span class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut in diam </span>
 <span class="boxLike">
  <nobr>
   <span class="comment">Span out of div</span>
   <span class="like">Span out of div 2</span>
  </nobr>
 </span>
</div>
```

[Code in link](http://jsfiddle.net/40f3mqzo/)

Comment: Get the `offsetTop + height` of the parent element and `offsetTop` of child element. Now compare both values. if the child element's value is more, then it is out of parent element.

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "coming out of div". It would be good if you provide us with jsfiddle or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the result of computing div and span offset and height. From the values you can say the span is outside the div http://jsfiddle.net/40f3mqzo/5/.

```
console.log("offset: " + $(".divMain").offset().top);
console.log("height: " + $(".divMain").height());
console.log("comment: " + $(".comment").offset().top);
```